# Sum unique ID's within groups and in total

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to count the number of unique ClientID in given time period in PowerBI. The trick is that the client can be a member of one or more groups and if he/she is in more then one group I need the sum to count his/her ID as one for each group.

My basic idea was to use measure to sum "ones" for each unique ClientID in fact table in given time period.

```
CALCULATE(
   SUMX(
      VALUES('fact'[ClientID]); 1
      );
   DATESBETWEEN('fact'[actionDate]; [start]; [end])
)
```

It basically work, if client take many actions in given time period his ID is counted only once, but when the client is  taking actions as a member of two or more groups in this time period - his ID should count as one for each group.

The GroupName is one of column in fact table as well.

Comment: Have you tried `DISTINCTCOUNT('fact'[ClientID])`?

Comment: DISTINCTCOUNT will not change anything. Still i will get ClientID counted only once even if it will be member of two or more groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like:

```
CALCULATE(
   COUNTROWS(SUMMARIZE('fact';'fact'[ClientID];'fact'[GroupID]));
   DATESBETWEEN('fact'[actionDate]; [start]; [end])
)
```

Comment: Flawless victory!

Thank You, works like charm.
I was experimenting with SUMMARIZECOLUMNS, but no luck.